# InnerJoin Joomla Not Working

Tags: joomla2.5, inner-join

What wrong?

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);        
$query = "SELECT jml.*,grkt.*,grk.*,jml.*"
."\n , FROM #__egerak_subutama AS grk"
."\n , inner join #__users AS jml ON jml.username = grk.username"
."\n , inner join #__egerak_kenyataan AS grkt ON grkt.kategori = grk.kategori"  
."\n , where actdate <= '$currYear- ". sprintf("%02d", $currMonth) . " - " . sprintf("%02d", $currDay). " '"
."\n , AND enddate >= '$currYear-". sprintf("%02d", $currMonth) . "-" . sprintf("%02d", $currDay). "'"
."\n , AND kodunit LIKE '%$ppdlms%'";
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM lpk_egerak_subutama AS grk , inner join lpk_users AS jml ON jml.username =' at line 2 SQL=SELECT jml.*,grkt.*,grk.*,jml.* , FROM lpk_egerak_subutama AS grk , inner join lpk_users AS jml ON jml.username = grk.username , inner join lpk_egerak_kenyataan AS grkt ON grkt.kategori = grk.kategori , where actdate <= '2013- 04 - 15 ' , AND enddate >= '2013-04-15' , AND kodunit LIKE '%%'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);        
$query = "SELECT jml.*,grkt.*,grk.*,jml.*"
."\n FROM #__egerak_subutama AS grk"
."\n inner join #__users AS jml ON jml.username = grk.username"
."\n inner join #__egerak_kenyataan AS grkt ON grkt.kategori = grk.kategori"  
."\n where actdate <= '$currYear- ". sprintf("%02d", $currMonth) . " - " . sprintf("%02d", $currDay). " '"
."\n AND enddate >= '$currYear-". sprintf("%02d", $currMonth) . "-" . sprintf("%02d", $currDay). "'"
."\n AND kodunit LIKE '%$ppdlms%'";
```

Remove all the commas from the start of the line. You are getting the error because the comma makes mysql expect another item to select not the from keyword.

Comment: Thank David Fritsch, can i show result with this query: $db->setQuery($query);
   $results = $db->loadObjectList();
   
   if ($results){
      foreach($results as $result) 
              {
         echo $result->username;
         echo $result->kategori; 
                 
         
         } }